# Qt: default value of variable in class

Tags: c++, qt, class, variables, default

When creating my own class in Qt I would like my variables in the class to have a standard/default value if I haven't set them to anything. It would be perfect if this was possible to set in the h-file so I don't have to do it in each instance method of my class. You can see what I want to do in the code below. In the example myBool would have the value of false and myInt the value of 0 when the object have been created. Is this possible at all?

In myclass.h:

```
class MyClass
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
MyClass();
   ~MyClass();
    bool myBool = false; //I want to set myBool and myInt to a default/standard value
    int myInt = 0; 
};
```

Comment: You will be able to do that in C++0x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt follows the rules of C++, and one rule is to use constructors to initialize your members.

```
MyClass::MyClass() : myBool(false), myInt(0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately what you are asking for is not available in current C++. In C++0x you can do that, but for now you may use the initializer list:

```
class MyClass
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass() : myBool(false), myInt(0) { }
   ~MyClass();
    bool myBool;
    int myInt;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

### I wanna have my default value!

No, there is no "direct" way in current C++ to have this "default" behaviour for built-in values.

As already answered in the two other questions, you'll need to provide the values in each constructor of MyClass.

### But I REALLY need it!!!

But if you **really** need it, there is one way to have it indirectly: Wrapping your built-in type inside a templated class overloading its supported operators.

This way, you will be able to write the following code :

```
void foo()
{
   bool b ;            // WRONG : Not initialized
   Variable<bool> bb ; // Ok : Initialized to false
   
   int i ;             // WRONG : Not initialized
   Variable<int> ii ;  // Ok : Initialized to 0

   // etc.
}
```

The needed code is, for example, for bool :

```
template<typename T>
class Variable
{
   T value_ ;

   public :
      Variable() ;
      Variable(const T & rhs) ;
      Variable(const Variable & rhs) ;

      Variable & operator = (const T & rhs) ;
      Variable & operator = (const Variable & rhs) ;

      operator T() const ;

      // define all other desired operators here
} ;
```

And then, coding the methods to have the desired behaviour. For example :

```
template<typename T>
inline Variable<T>::Variable()
   : value_(0)
{
}

// For the fun, I want all booleans initialized to true !
template<>
inline Variable<bool>::Variable()
   : value_(true)
{
}

// For the fun, I want all doubles initialized to PI !
template<>
inline Variable<double>::Variable()
   : value_(3.1415)
{
}

// etc.

template<typename T>
inline Variable<T>::operator T() const
{
   return value_ ;
}

// etc.
```

The list of operators can be quite great, depending on what you want to do with the variable. For example, and integer will have all arithmetic operators. And all operators are not overloadable (and should not be, in this case), so you won't have all built-in behaviours.

Anyway, as you can see, you can specialize methods for some types, if particular behaviour is desired.

Completing the list of methods, as well as correctly coding them is a very good C++ exercice.

Once done, all you need is to declare your variable :

```
class MyClass
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   MyClass();
   ~MyClass();

   Variable<bool> myBool ;  // it will be set to false, as defined
   Variable<int> myInt ; // it will be set to 0, as defined
};
```

And then, you will use it as follows:

```
void foo()
{
   MyObject o ;
   o.myBool = true ;
   
   if(o.myInt == 0)
   {
      ++o.myInt ;
   }
}
```

Makes sure all the code of you wrapper class is inlined and inside included header files, and you'll have no performance cost when compiled with "release" options.

Comment: That's not worth the effort, and there is (as far as my experience goes) no case where you could not use construcors (as the accepted answer says). correct me if I am wrong...
And in the End you just wrapped the Construcor usage into a template class...

Comment: @soxs060389: Of course, you're right. But I was unwilling to provide the same answer as the two others. My solution is the very very last ultimate solution you would use if you really really really really needed to have the built-ins initialized (hence, the title "But I REALLY need it!!!").